# Can you force yum to ignore an exclude list?

Tags: yum

We are using a custom repository with RHEL 5.x. We were running into a ton of issues and conflicts when trying to run an update (issues with yum 32bit packages conflicting with x64 packages). To get around this, I added

```
exclude=*.i386
```

to /etc/yum.conf. This worked great, until I had to install compat-libstdc++-296, which apparently is 32bit only. I checked on RH's site, and the only package listed verified that. So, when I try to specify the full package name compat-libstdc++-296.i386, the exclusion list blocks it from being installed.

Is there any way to force yum to temporarily ignore the exclusion list? Something like

```
yum install compat-libstdc++-296.i386 --ignore-exclude
```

Not that it's hard to comment out the line, run the install, and then uncomment, my major concern is that we have around 300 servers this needs to be run on, and that's a lot of hands editing text files. I'd much prefer being able to copy and paste a command, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the yum man page:

```
--disableexcludes=[all|main|repoid]
       Disable  the excludes defined in your config files. Takes one of
       three options:
       all == disable all excludes
       main == disable excludes defined in [main] in yum.conf
       repoid == disable excludes defined for that repo
```

Comment: Yup, just found this. I didn't check the yum man page, just the yum help text. It's less than helpful by stating: "--disableexcludes=[repo] disable exclude from main, for a repo or for everything". Thanks for providing the all flag, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to rpm -ivh install the file via URL.  If that doesn't work because of dependency issues, try with the dependencies first.

Comment: This would probably work in most cases, our scenario is awkward because we're using anycast, and don't have a real IP to send the HTTP request to. Good suggestion for most cases like I said though.